# In the World bank database, why is there no GDP data for switzerland between 1970 and 1979?

Tags: worldbank, gdp

The World bank database has a gap for Switzerland between 1970 and 1979: 
[Worldbank GDP data for Switzerland](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?locations=CH).

Do you know why is there this gap and what is the best source to fill it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gdp+site%3Aadmin.ch might be a starting point.

Comment: [Data on the Swiss Statistics website](http://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/portal/en/index/themen/04/02/01.html) start from 1995 only. I couldn't find data for the 1970-1979 period on that site. OECD provides [historical GDP data for Switzerland](https://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?queryid=350#) over that period, values are flagged as estimates.